# How to publish an ASP.NET web app in local area network in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have just made an ASP.NET web application with VS2015 (framework .NET4.6.1). The project is on my computer but I want to make it accessible from other computers in my office (I think we have a local area network). I have IIS installed. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The most solid (but also more complicated way) is to install a server somewhere in the office which can only be accessed from inside. That said, these are the steps I used to do this a while ago, though I can't guarantee they'll work flawlessly (or at all anymore).

**Configure IIS Express (VS2015) to accept outside network connections (on the same subnet)**

1. Find out your local IP address, computer user name, and the project port number.
2. Go to PROJECT_FOLDER.vs\config\ and open applicationhost.config in any plain text file editor (recommended: Atom or VS2015)
3. In the applicationhost.config, find the sites section in system.applicationHost. In there, you will find a section . Under , add a new binding with . Save, and close.
4. Open an elevated windows command prompt or Powershell (recommended).
5. Execute the following commands: "netsh http add urlacl url=http://IP_ADDRESS:SITE_PORT/ user=USERNAME", "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=SITE_PORT profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow"

Done

---

**When you're finished testing, you should disable the connection settings again.**

1. Remove the bindings in the application.config file you just added.
2. Run the command "http delete urlacl url=http://IP_ADDRESS:SITE_PORT/"
3. Delete the firewall rule with "Delete rule name="IISExpressWeb"" in an elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Use your IP address for deploying in your work network.

Use this [link](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_framework/article.php/c19419/Deploying-ASPNET-Applications--Part-1.htm) (Step-by-Step with pictures) for publishing in your local network.
(Supports VS2015)

[Link 2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b07128/deploy-Asp-Net-website-on-iis-in-our-local-machine/) : Better Deployment with Support from VS 2010 to VS 2015

Comment: I have followed Link 2. The problem is that it doesn't execute angular.